# Problem with opacity in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, opacity

I try to solve a problem that appears in IE8. Html is very simple:

```
<div id="overlay">
</div>
<div id="imgcontainer">
     <div>
         <div id="source">
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

When I set (using jQuery) opacity of "#source" element with "0" in IE I can see the background of #overlay, not #imgcontainer > div, but why?
There is a javascript code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#source").css({
        opacity: "0",
    });
    $("#overlay").css({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height(),
        display: "block",
        opacity: "0.6"
    });

    $("#imgcontainer").css({
        zIndex: 2,
        position: "fixed",
        opacity: "1",
        left: "0",
        right: "0",
        top: "100px",
        display: "block"
    });
});
```

You can try live example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s9Rr/).
**UPD:**
After some experiments I found the solution. It's really html\css issue, so I made some refactoring of code and remove jQuery tag. Imagine we have such html murk up:

```
<body>
        <div id="d1">
            <div id="d2">
                <div id="d3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

and the css styles:

```
body {
    background-color: #c8c8c8;
}

#d1 {
    background-color: #6c0922;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
}

#d2 {
    background-color: #146122;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#d3 {
    background-color: #0080c0;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px 65px;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

At first look all is ok, we expect that `#d3` become transparent and we can see `#d2` background(dark green). But not so simple in IE7\8. In IE we can see body!(grey) background through `#d2` and `#d1`. All magic in `#d1` you guessed it. When we remove `filter: alpha(opacity = 100);` all work correctly.

You can ask - but why you set opacity = 1 to the element which is non-transparent now? I don't know :). May be in some reason you should use this behavior. Very interesting and unexpected behavior.

You can play with this example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s9Rr/17/).

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: this more of a CSS/HTML problem that it is jQuery, if you remove all the jQuery and make it pure CSS, u will see that the problem will persist. Never encountered such thing, would be interesting to find out the cause and solution of this.

Comment: @Dan: agree, this is more CSS/HTML problem

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.  I did a lot of searching and reading and found IE8 doesn't use the css for opacity other browsers use.  Here is my CSS that I used for IE8:

```
#loading-div-background {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:gray;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /* Next 2 lines IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75);
}
```

However, it still didn't work with position:fixed, but once I put in position:absolute it started working.

Comment: How many times have answers from SO saved me time?  Enough to make me want to help others!      :-)

Answer (score 6):

IE8 doesn't support the CSS attribute `opacity` you have to use an MS filter instead:

```
    opacity: "0",
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50); /*change value to suit your needs*/
```

That's not all though. This only works when the element is positioned, thankfully you have that already so it will work. For future reference if you don't have any position set, you can add `zoom: 1` to the selector and it will work in IE :)

Comment: You may need `filter` for IE6/7 and `-ms-filter` for IE8. IE9 does support `opacity`. You'll still need to specify `opacity` in addition to `filter` to get it to work for all browsers.

Comment: As I remember jquery takes care of the 'opacity' key if the browser is IE (if you set it from jquery, it will be the 'filter: ...' param). But correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is not true, he is changing the css using jQuery. And the way he is doing it, jQuery will automatically take care of the cross-browser compatibility. If you look carefully, the `div`s are transparent in IE but in the case of `div#source` it is even making it's parent, and only where they intersect, also transparent, which is where his problem is

Comment: As I mentioned I use jQuery, you can try my example in IE8, press F12 and inspect #source element. You can see that jQuery set "filter:  alpha(opacity=0); ZOOM: 1;" attribute automatically, but in firefox for example it equal to "opacity: 0;"

Comment: This does not work for me. Filter opacity is completely ignored in IE8 with fixed position elements.