# jQuery animate opacity with div.fadehover not working at all in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

jQuery animate opacity with div.fadehover works well in Chrome, FF and Safari, not working at all in IE8. No fade at all. http://www.youarenottheproblem.com/
Have tried filter:inherit; but maybe not putting it in right place - any ideas?
Explain it like I am 5 please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4615303/1524085

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with opacity in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615147/problem-with-opacity-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

In IE8, the CSS property opacity isn't respected. You'll need to also do `"filter":"-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";"` in the hover case, and `"filter":"-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"` in the callback.

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
```

Fixed code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0", "filter" : "-ms-filter":"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1", "filter" : "-ms-filter":"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"}, "slow");
});

});
```

Comment: Can you paste the solution into my code by any chance? I am not at all a pro.

Comment: I've edited my response with the fixed and original code. In the future, it's a good idea to include your own code when you start. Or use jsfiddle.net or codepen.io to include it in an editable way. You usually get faster responses that way. :)

Comment: Thanks, but still not working in IE. Copy and pasted exactly.

Comment: Try one more time with my edit. Looks like the syntax for 8 is different than with 6 and 7. You can leave what you have and just add the ", "filter" : "-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"` stuff to get ie 6, 7, and 8 to play along

Comment: Unfortunately getting a syntax error. Will try and figure out.